# Desktop applications: how would you hide unwanted message box popups form 3'd party libraries

Tags: .net, desktop-application

I have to write a demo application for a customer and currently use free .net 3'd party trial library. If customer would be pleased with demo we will purchase commercial version  for the project.

Meanwhile trial version occasionally throws "You are using trial limited functionality" message box that can ruin demonstration.

How would you personally block (close) such popups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you should not attempt to do that, ie programatically overriding the behaviour of the 3rd party trial lib. If you are building a demo, your targeted customers should understand what a demo is and go along with this.

If it really is annoying, then contact the 3rd party vendor and ask for a time limited full version without the popping message boxes. In my experience, they are usually keen to helping you out in such matters.

**EDIT**

Theory aside, have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/WindowInterceptor.aspx?fid=1070466&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2624936) article, might be easier than your no-interaction-win-service solution.

Comment: Nice comment, though I have only one day to prepare demo that I started on holidays. I guess I should put trial functionality into windows desktopless service with try/catches.

Comment: I decided to mark your answer as accepted though copy/pasted suggestion from link you provided didn't work fo some reason. Finally I created background thread that regularly "finds window by title" and sends WM_CLOSE to that :)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a technical solution, but I think there is something strange on your approach.

If you are providing the user with a trial version of your software, it means it is (more or less) developed and finalized. It also means your choices in terms of technologies and third-party components are already made. As such you probably already have a license for those third-party components. Then why would you ship a trial version of your software with trial versions of its components. The users want to try your software, they don't care about the underlying components.

To use another example, suppose you want to try a car before buying, would you prefer to try a prototype of this car instead of a finalized, tested car?

Comment: Thank you, @Johann! I guess customeres would ask us to give them access to play with demo via Internet. At this moment we shall purchase library (it's pretty expensive). We just want to minimize budget at present if the project will fail at the very beginning.

Comment: Then I think (as tzup said) you can try and make an arrangement with the third-party vendor.